# An error while trying to execute tests on python 3.10 with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.10

If I try to execute tests using `pytest` with python 3.10 I got the following error:

```
TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from alias
```

Google says it's a known problem, but I found no way to solve it.
Tests start fine if I launch them with 3.9

Answer (score 96):

This issue seems to be fixed in [pytest version 6.2.5](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/).

Please see: [Fix assertion rewriting on Python 3.10](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/8540)

Comment: I am using pytest version 7.1.2 and still have same issue, how can I fix this problem locally?

Comment: @John I was able to fix this issue by upgrading pytest to version `7.1.2`.

Comment: weird stuff going on mate

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I ran `poetry add --dev pytest@latest` as `poetry new` constrained `pytest` to `^5.2` by default.

Answer (score 36):

Just upgrade the `pytest` PyPI package:

```
pip install -U pytest
```

Comment: I still have same problem, is this normal output after this call? - $ pip install -U pytest
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable, others are that Requirement is already satisfied

Comment: @John I guess your problem is related to the `pip` itself. Try to update the `pip` via `python -m pip install -U pip` or install the `pytest` through `python -m pip install -U pytest`

Comment: I think this is the correct answer (that the solution is to update pytest) but the command to run can be improved. Since we're using poetry to manage our project's dependencies, including its dev dependencies, we should run `poetry remove --dev pytest && poetry add --dev pytest`, which will remove whichever version of pytest was added to the project when it was created and then add the latest version. For me, that meant going from `5.4.3` to `7.1.2`. This process also removed the old transitive dependencies of pytest and then added the new transitive dependencies for the new version.

Comment: When I did the above steps, and then ran `poetry run pytest`, it worked for me. Since this was a brand new project with no source code yet, and just the initial, automatically-created test, my output said: `1 passed in 0.01s`

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile...I was getting this error during

```
python3 setup.py pytest
```

in a library. When I did the following:

```
pytest -q tests/test_mypackage.py
```

The error lost, and I got the tests running.