# pytest cannot be executed from Python 3.10.4

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.10

I already saw one old post regarding this topic - [An error while trying to execute tests on python 3.10 with pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528842/an-error-while-trying-to-execute-tests-on-python-3-10-with-pytest/72293653#72293653),

I am having the same problem, Python 3.10.4 and pytest 7.1.2, when I start command:

$ pipenv run pytest

I get an error:

```
$ pipenv run pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-4.0.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: **DIR**, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
____________________ ERROR collecting test/test_person.py _____________________
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:939: in _find_spec
    ???
E   AttributeError: 'AssertionRewritingHook' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**LOCAL_PATH**\.virtualenvs\iamdb-2ZawZA6J\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:668: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1002: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:941: in _find_spec
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:915: in _find_spec_legacy
    ???
**LOCAL_PATH**\.virtualenvs\iamdb-2ZawZA6J\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py:162: in find_module
    source_stat, co = _rewrite_test(self.config, fn_pypath)
**LOCAL_PATH**\.virtualenvs\iamdb-2ZawZA6J\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py:412: in _rewrite_test
    co = compile(tree, fn.strpath, "exec", dont_inherit=True)
E   TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from alias
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.16 seconds ===========================
```

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Well, you are using pytest 4.0.0, not 7.1.2, so this is to be expected.

Comment: I see, but when I check: $ pytest --version, I get:
pytest 7.1.2

Comment: Looks like your tests runs in a different environment, check your venv (e.g. pipenv).

Comment: Can I maybe downgrade pytest version?

Comment: You are using 4.0.0, this is an old version not working with Python 3.10 - not sure what you mean by downgrading. You need to upgrade it instead in your venv.

Comment: I see, huh, any advice of how to do that? I just got this fresh project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244852/discussion-between-john-and-mrbean-bremen).

Comment: Updating some other packages might help, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment from Marco Bonelli, pytest had no correct version.
So command:

```
pipenv update pytest
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue when using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/). In my case, `pytest` was set to v5.2:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"
```

After updating `pytest` to `^7.1.2`, things started working.

```bash
poetry add -D pytest@latest
```

```ini
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^7.1.2"
```

Comment: This helped me find the root cause on my project, which was the min python version of `3.4`, which apparently prevented poetry from using the latest pytest version. Upped it to `3.7` (because I can just do that) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the recent pytest version 7.1.2.

- Downgrading did not help.
- Removing my pyproject.toml file also did not help. (Thought it might be a pylint configuration issue.)

In the error message another package occurred (that I did not use at all in that specific project but that was nevertheless installed in my environment): dash.

=> **Updating dash to the latest version** resolved the issue.

=> I have no idea why.

=> If pytest does not run, check if **updating some other packages** that occur in the error message helps.

---

```
PS C:\python_env\workspace\hello_world_with_tests> pytest
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main 
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 187, in console_main
    code = main()
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 145, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 324, in _prepareconfig
    config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 102, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config: Config = outcome.get_result()
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1016, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1304, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1187, in _preparse
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 287, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\dash\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .dash import Dash, no_update  # noqa: F401,E402
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_current_traceback' from 'werkzeug.debug.tbtools' (C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py)
```